# How not to show the command response but only display conditional response

Tags: linux, shell-script

```
ping -c 5 test && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```

Output: success / failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect the output to `/dev/null`

```
ping -c 5 test > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "success" || echo "failure"
```

`2>&1` redirects any error messages (not necessarily) `stderr` to `stdin`